# How to get progress values from SeekBar created in ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, mobile, listadapter, seekbar

I'm curently working on my first Android app, which is my first pice of java code at all, i think I got pretty far already but now I'm stuck on the following topic:

I have a ListActivity which shows rowViews from a custom ListAdapter generated from json objects. Generaly there are 3 types of objects:

Rooms, which neither have a button nor a slider. Those are handled like this in my ListActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.d(TAG,"Area" + l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + "clicked");
    handleControlItemActions((JSONObject)l.getItemAtPosition(position));
}
```

Switchable devices, which have a toggle button to be switched on and off are handled like this (onObjectSwitch is defined in xml as onClick action for the button):

```
    public void onObjectSwitch (final View view) {
     Log.d(TAG,"Object" + view.getId()+ " clicked");
     handleControlItemActions((JSONObject)l.getItemAtPosition(position));
}
```

Dimmable devices, which have a SeekBar, and here is my problem: 
I know the "onSeekBarChangeListener", but I have no clue how I can set it to the SeekBars which are inside the rowViews from my Activity class.
The bars are created by the Listadapter like this:

```
    case 1:
    textView.setText((String)controlItem.get("name") + " " +(String)controlItem.getString("actual")+"°C");
    slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    slider.setId(position);
    slider.setProgress(controlItem.getInt("setPoint"));
    slider.setMax(controlItem.getInt("max"));
    break;
```

Can anyone tell me how to handle those sliders? Or am I not even on the right track to manage those widgets?

Thanks in advance to everyone (and sorry for my spelling ;) )!

Comment: Wierd, cant you just set .setOnSeekBarChangeListener to the slider in your code?

Comment: When I set the OnSeekBarChangeListener in the listAdapter it only accepts static variables and functions. 

I cant access the "slider" object from another class to set the listener in my ListView, so i have no idea where & how to set the listner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it:
just define the listadapter as a subclass inside of the listactivity, now you're able to reffere to the methods without flagging them "static".